# Other Functions $f(x)$ for which Rational $x \neq 0$ Implies that $f(x)$ is Irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

In 1768, Johann Lambert showed that if $x$ is a nonzero rational number, then neither $e^{x}$ nor $\tan x$ can be rational. And so, for example, because $\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$, we may infer that $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and in particular, $\pi$, is irrational.

My question is, are there other functions $f(x)$ similar to $e^{x}$ and $\tan x$ from which we may infer that if $x$ is nonzero and rational then $f(x)$ is irrational?

Comment: $\ln x$ prolly.

Comment: $x+\sqrt 2$?${}{}$

Comment: $f(x) = \log |x|$ also works, because of $e^{x}$.

Comment: $x+k$, $kx$, $k/x$, etc where $k \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$, as well as all trigonometric functions

Comment: In the case of $f(x)=e^x$ the Lindemann Weierstrass theorem gives an even stronger result : For algebraic $x\ne 0$, $e^x$ is transcendental.